# Why did I receive "IMMEDIATE ACTION NEEDED" email for OpenID EOL?

Tags: support, login, openid, email

I think I already added my email address:

[image: My Logins page, showing Stack Exchange and Yahoo accounts]

But 18 hours ago, I received an email:

> **You must update your account authentication options TODAY in order for your account to stay active.**

Why the bold text? Didn't I already do what you requested?

Comment: Maybe the email batch was created 6 to 8 weeks ago and not updated when they send out the email today?

Comment: @rene good chance they don't even check and send to everyone having a login that is about to be "aborted", following the "Better Safe Than Sorry" logic.

Comment: When did you add the yahoo credentials?  Very recently, or quite some time ago?

Comment: @Servy Yahoo was my first and only account until I received the first OpenID deprecation email.